# I did not understand this question based on circular race

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How Two persons, X and Y, start together from the same point and run on a 4 km circular track in a race of 16 km. The ratio of their speeds is 3 : 7. How often do they meet on the track in the race, if they both run in the clockwise direction?
a. Once 
b. Twice 
c. Thrice 
d. Five times 
e.Cannot be determined

Comment: Write formulae for the distance each has travelled after time $t$.  Let the speed of X be $3v$ and the speed of Y be $7v$.  Let $x$ and $y$ be the distance each has travelled.  So $x = 3vt$ and $y = 7vt$.  When will Y lap X for the first time?  When he is $4$ ahead so try to solve $y = x + 16$.  When will he lap X the second time?  When he is $8$ ahead.  Keep going until the solution is greater than 16 since the race will be over.

Comment: use relative speeds and assume X is standing still, then give Y a speed of v  - he will run for t = 16 / v, his speed of gaining on X is (4 / 7) v - after t has elapsed, he'll have gained (4 x 16) / 7 on X, which is 9.14 km ahead, so i make that to be lapped twice - or just work out how far ahead Y is a t the end if he runs at 7, then you can also see that every whole 4km is one lap, as a check you can redo that with running at 14, and see the result is the same